# Google Apps Script If Or Statement

Tags: google-apps-script

I would like to trigger a function based on 3 cells on one sheet. This is what I have.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var summarySht = 'Summary';
  if(e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() !== summarySht || 
e.range.getA1Notation() !== 'D1' && e.range.getA1Notation() !== 'D2' && 
e.range.getA1Notation() !== 'D3') return;
    updateFormulasBasedOnSelection()
};
```

I was able to limit it to one sheet and the three cells. Now I would like two things -

1. I'd like to not trigger the function if any of those cells are blank
2. If you can, please explain why my code above works.

I'm confused on the use of ||, && and !==. Can someone explain this in layman terms because I see !== and I think not equal to, I see && between each cell and I think all three of them have to have been the edited cells yet neither of these are working for me as I think of them logically.

Comment: Review the logical operators section on your favorite JavaScript language reference. Note that short circuit operators like `&amp;&amp;` and `||` will not evaluate both sides for every coerced Boolean evaluation of the left hand operand. Review also the operator precedence rankings.

Comment: Thank you. I'll do more research.